# How to lock the screen from usage in windows?

Tags: c#, windows

I am working on screen time in which I should stop the user from using the device after certain time. It should work similar to microsoft family safety screen time.

Things I did so far:

- I locked the screen using `lockWorkStation` function. But the user
  could login again.
- So I blocked the input using    `blockInput` function. But the user
  can still use ctrl+alt+delete to    get over it.

What is the way to block the entire screen from usage after the allowed time gets over? Is it possible to do with windows c#?

Comment: An user with administrative privileges will always have a tool to do what he wants (thanks God)...exactly what should happen? User simply can't interact with computer in any way? Not even login with a different account?

Comment: might be a problem with the safe mode ....

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti No. Only with his account. User can login through different account. App has no control over it. My approach doesnt help.

Comment: If it can't log-on again with his account then...do you want permanently disable it?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti It will be enabled next day. user is allowed to use the system for certain time a day. After allowed time gets over, login should be disabled for rest of the day. Next day it will be enabled.

Comment: OK then it must be done by a process running with administrative privileges (and user should not have them). Just **disable** that user and perform LockWorkStation(). A scheduled task (or your own service with admin privs) will start at midnight to re-enable all disabled users.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Nice way to do. I ll try it.